# Do NIO selectors use event notifications by default?

Tags: java, events, nio, kqueue

I found [this article](http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/epoll) saying OpenJDK uses epoll on linux, but does anybody know if Selector implementations use kqueue, dev/poll etc over traditional polling where available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. java.nio.channels.Selector.open() returns different implementations depending on your underlying operating system. Eg. If you are using a JRE from sun/oracle you will get:

```
Windows 
sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl

Mac OS 
sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl

Linux 
sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl

Solaris
sun.nio.ch.PollSelectorImpl
```

Comment: Java7 update: That being said: The windows part is pretty slow compared to native IOCP. The windows selector cannot select more than 1024 channels and thus is pretty slow... Use AIO if possible under windows